# Unable to read file using "load" in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble executing the following code. When I run the code, it shows me:

```
Error using load
Unable to read file 'motionDB.mat': no such file or directory.
Error in:  else  load ('motionDB.mat');
```

However, when i remove the second "if loop" it runs properly.

My Code:

```
  user_filter='gaussian';  
  if(strcmpi(user_filter,'gaussian')==1)
         h = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 1);% gauss filter
         if ~exist('gaussianDB.mat')
              createHistDB( num_bins,Dir,srcFiles,filter,h,num_red_bins,num_green_bins,num_blue_bins,B );
         end
         else  load('gaussianDB.mat');
    end

 if(strcmpi(user_filter,'motion')==1)% motion filter
      h=fspecial('motion', 20, 45);
      if ~exist('motionDB.mat')
              createHistDB( num_bins,Dir,srcFiles,filter,h,num_red_bins,num_green_bins,num_blue_bins, B );
      end
       else  load('motionDB.mat');
    end
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've mixed up where the `else` and `end` statements in your code are going.  Instead of:

```
if(strcmpi(user_filter,'gaussian')==1)
     h = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 1);% gauss filter
     if ~exist('gaussianDB.mat')
          createHistDB( num_bins,Dir,srcFiles,filter,h,num_red_bins,num_green_bins,num_blue_bins,B );
     end
     else  load('gaussianDB.mat');
end
```

try:

```
if(strcmpi(user_filter,'gaussian')==1)
     h = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 1);% gauss filter
     if ~exist('gaussianDB.mat')
          createHistDB( num_bins,Dir,srcFiles,filter,h,num_red_bins,num_green_bins,num_blue_bins,B );
     else  
          load('gaussianDB.mat');
     end
end
```